# Calling DB2 Table Valued Function from Excel

Tags: excel, db2, db2-400

I have created a User Defined Table Valued Function in DB2 which takes in two parameters and returns a Table.

Calling the UDTVF from **IBM i Access Client Solutions** (Version: 1.1.7.1 Build: 7290) >> **Run SQL Scripts** works fine returning a table of results:

```
-- SELECT *
-- FROM TABLE(<library>.<udtvf>(<param. 1>,<Param. 2>)) AS ResultsTable

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(DPLIB06.FISMOSLSWAR(1,2017)) AS ResultsTable
```

I have an ODBC DSN defined that points to DB2.  This DSN works fine as a Data Connection within MS Excel, Crystal Reports, etc. etc. and has, up to this point, worked fine even with some very complex queries.

When I attempt to add the above query to an Excel Sheet via the MS Query Editor I get the following warning/error messages:

```
SQL Query can't be represented graphically. Continue anyway?
```

No big deal with this warning: I always click **OK** and life goes on...
but then I get

```
Could not add the table 'TABLE(DPLIB06.FISMOSLSWAR(1'.
```

So...  Can someone give me the syntax for calling a DB2 User Defined Table Valued Function (with two parameters) from Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Try working around the problem. For example, try creating a VIEW in the database to represent the query on the table function.  Then in Excel, select from that view.

Comment: Mao - The reason for using a UDTVF is because a **VIEW** does not accept **Parameters**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works:

Using the MS Query Editor enter a simple query:

```
SELECT 'A' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Close the Editor returning results to your Excel

From the Excel **Data >> Connections** menu select your Connection and expose its **Properties**.  In the **Definition** replace the **Command text** with the query that references the UDTVF